# Multiple Column Filter

Tags: excel, filter

I have a scenario as below:

[image]

What I want : if any cell in column C-G is not-empty - 'y', then show all the row items in column A and B. I want as below:

[image]

How to do it? Cheers.

Comment: Set up a formula in column H that says if there is any y in the preceding cells of that row i.e. `=OR(C2="y",D2="y",E2="y",F2="y",G2="y")` then drag at down.

Comment: Thanks. what if I have different values than 'y'? what if I want to select Only filled cells.

Comment: You could also use an Advanced Filter https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine for using a helper column (say column-H) then try the following:

In column-H put the formula =COUNTIF(C2:G2,"y")

This formula will count the number of 'y' in row-2.

Copy this formula down below up till end of your data.

Now you can filter your data on column-H for value equal to zero.

Hope this Helps.